# Allow other users within domain to use google apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have written some code within my Master spreadsheet, and then added the script ID to the library on other spreadsheets owned by me.  I am able to run the scripts on those other spreadsheets.  However, when I share Edit level access to other users and the scripts don't run when they log in.  I have to share each spreadsheet on an individual basis, as they contain confidential information (e.g., payroll info).

Here is the process I used.

1. Get the script ID from the Master spreadsheet.
2. On each individual's payroll spreadsheet I added the script ID as an included Library.  There is a toggle for Development Mode, set to ON (although, I'm not clear on what that is).
3. Add references to call code from Master.

Again, everything works as expected when I'm logged in, but not when the users are.  First of all, the onOpen trigger doesn't work (it should make a menu and then jump to the current month's sheet.)  If that user opens Script Editor and attempts to run the script, it says something like, "User doesn't have access to library Master or it has been deleted."

Hopefully I'm just such a noob that there is an obvious oversight.  If you notice it, please let me know how to correct this!

Thank you in advance,
Neill

Comment: Have you shared the Master sheet with all domain users?  I believe they need access to that file.

Comment: I cannot share it with everyone, as it is the main storage location for other people's confidential details.  So, I will attempt to make a generic empty file and share it with the whole domain, and add my scripts there.  I will check back in with you in a few minutes.

Comment: Maybe even make a Script file and place the code there, instead of embedded in a spreadsheet.

Comment: You are right.  It worked when I made a new spreadsheet file, and added a script to that file.  I set the sharing as you suggested, and it worked!

Comment: I don't know how to make a script file that is not embedded inside of a spreadsheet.  I guess since I'm just learning on my own, I noticed that on Google Sheets, there's a menu item for Script Editor... and that's what I've always done.  How can I make a standalone?

Comment: In Google Drive use the **New** button, then select _More_ and you will see _Google Apps Script_

Comment: or go to script.google.com ;)

Comment: Excellent. You all are so helpful.Thank you!